# How can I know how long `dd` cloning will take?

Tags: command-line, clone, dd

I have to `dd` a couple of 1TB hard drives. They are taking several hours to clone and I was wondering if there was any way possible of knowing how fast they are going, how much they have done and how long will they take to copy the rest.

All I can see is the terminal with the command running. When I run `ps -e` at least I know that `dd` is working from the CPU usage shown, but I have no way of knowing how much it has done or how long it will take to finish.

Kind of makes me crazy.

Comment: there is another discussion with various ways of doing this http://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd

Comment: The duplicate question has a more updated answer.

Comment: @Garrett correct. Hence why this was marked as a duplicate of that one. Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the program `pv` for any piped stream to see a live report of data transfered. It can be used for any application using pipes. It is also a great tool for seeing rate of transfer to things like USB, External disks, networked computers.

```
dd if=infile | pv > outfile
```

Or for direct copying, just use this:

```
pv infile > outfile
```

Example:

```
sudo pv /dev/sda1 > /home/user/sda1.ext4.img
```

Comment: Can you additionally add a case for creating a clone of a disc, like dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb with the pv command.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado: `pv /dev/sda > /dev/sdb`. Also gives you a nice progress bar.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail - Wait, are you saying I can clone a disc like that?

Comment: @LuisAlvarado, yes, you can clone a disc like that. Mech has used another partition as the output, but you could also output to a regular file named like "sda.img"

Comment: dont forget `dd if=/dev/sda | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb`

Comment: maybe even try the size argument `-s` in bytes of source

Comment: For those of you who can now finally monitor the throughput but wonder why it's <10kiB/s, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322224/120881

Answer (score 36):

Typical. When I ask something I then find the answer somehow (even if I looked for hours.. but magically I find it AFTER creating the question -.- ). Anyway for what I checked with `dd --help` which mentions at the end of the help (I can't really believe I did not see THAT) the following:

```
Sending a USR1 signal to a running `dd' process makes it
print I/O statistics to standard error and then resume copying.

   $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null& pid=$!
   $ kill -USR1 $pid; sleep 1; kill $pid
   18335302+0 records in
   18335302+0 records out
   9387674624 bytes (9.4 GB) copied, 34.6279 seconds, 271 MB/s
```

What this means is that in another terminal you would run the following line using the Process ID of the DD you want to check. For example in my case is Process Id 4112. You can see the process ID by typing `ps -e` and looking for dd or just `ps -e|grep dd` and looking at the number in the front. Take note of that number and then type in another terminal window `kill -USR1 4112; sleep 1;` This will give me the time, seconds elapsed since it began and how much is has copied. At least now I know it takes about 8 hours to copy 1TB of information at about 40MB/s.

Comment: `pv` is much more convenient though.

Comment: This didn't work on OSX, it just killed it... which is unfortunate, as it had already been running for an hour... :(

Comment: @balupton highly recommend you post that as a bug in launchpad. Maybe is something related to all OSX or your particular case. Just tried it right now (Not OSX) and it worked, so you might be the proud owner of a huge bug. Go kill it!

Comment: Do NOT run `kill $pid`. This might kill the copy proccess. @Luis your answer is a bit missleading. All you need to do is run `ps -a | grep dd` and then send the signal to aquired pid `kill -USR1 123456789` (where "123456789" is the pid).

Comment: @nux Hi friend and thanks for the comment. In this case, it is coming directly from the man page. Just in case, for DD, when it receives the dummy USR1, it behaves like a more verbose log, so it outputs the last line mentioned in the example.

Comment: @balupton "**On BSD systems, you need to send the INFO signal**. Linux doesn't have a SIGINFO and uses USR1 instead." [See here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11264/154671)

Answer (score 16):

Regarding using kill to display info on a Mac, you have to pass it the `-INFO` flag instead of the `-USR1` flag. And remember that it shows the info in the terminal where your dd process is running, so if you open a new tab to type `kill -INFO $PID` (where `$PID` is the number you found using `ps -e | grep dd`), you'll have to switch back to the tab where `dd` is running to see the output.

Now if only I could figure out how to display that output as GB or MB instead of plain bytes...

Comment: FYI on OSX it seems you can now press `CTRL + t` which gives you progress output. I'm not sure if this is a new feature, but it's available for me on OSX Catalina (10.15) and is much easier than most solutions here :)

Answer (score 4):

There is already another extended dd called `dcfldd` that do many funny stuff as this you are asking for http://dcfldd.sourceforge.net/

1. `sudo apt-get install dcfldd`
2. Instead of `dd` you write `dcfldd`

Comment: +1 but the last update to that app was in 2006. Even if it works I would still fall with the normal dd or pv until I had tried dcfldd with a lot of non-important information.